# DBT macro receives variable as string when dictionary is passed

Tags: dbt

I'm new to DBT world and facing a strange issue.
Database - Snowflake.
Attached  two test models , one test csv data file and one test macro file.

```
seed data file : sample_data.csv
----------------------------------------------------------------

subdimension,datasource,datasource_label,scoring_metric,weight
facebook_impressions,pathmatics_facebook,Pathmatics Facebook,total_year_impressions,5
facebook_engagement,facebook,Facebook,total_year_interactions,2.5
facebook_engagement,facebook,Facebook,interactions_per_post,2.5

-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm reading data from the seed csv file  using call statement and creating a dictionary using fromjson(query_result).
if you look at TEST1 model , this reading data as dictionary is coded there . This dictionary is then passed to the macro scoring and the macro  receives it as a dictionary as it should.
Now take a look at TEST2 model. It's the same thing but the only difference is , the reading data as a dictionary format is done through a macro called get_scoring_metrics .
Here TEST2 receives the dictionary from  get_scoring_metrics and pass it on to the macro scoring. But this time the macro scoring receives data as a string instead of a dictionary and throws the exception str object has no attribute items. If you compile the models , you will see it.
How is this possible? Both cases I'm using the same code.
I need data in dictionary format for ease of developing a complicated model .
Any solution will be appreciated . Thank you.

### MODEL TEST1 (WORKS CORRECTLY)

```
-- depends_on: {{ ref('sample_data') }}

{%- set datasource = 'facebook' -%}

    -- DICTIONARY THAT MAPS METRICS TO THEIR SUB-DIMENSIONS

{%- call statement('scoring_metric_query', fetch_result=True) -%}

    SELECT TO_JSON(PARSE_JSON('{'||LISTAGG(diq_subdim,',')||'}')) AS diq_metric
    FROM
        (
            SELECT subdim_name||':'||'['||scoring_metric||']' AS diq_subdim
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT '"'||subdimension ||'"' AS subdim_name,
                    LISTAGG(''''||scoring_metric ||'''' , ',') AS scoring_metric
                    FROM {{ ref('sample_data') }}
                    WHERE lower(datasource) = lower('{{ datasource }}')
                    GROUP BY subdimension
                ) T1
        ) T2

{%- endcall -%}

{% if execute %}

  {%- set query_result = load_result('scoring_metric_query')['data'][0][0] -%}
  {% set metric_dict = fromjson(query_result) %}

{% endif %}

{{
    scoring(
      datasource = datasource,
      metric_dict = metric_dict
    )
}}
```

---

### MODEL TEST2 (Which throws exception during compilation even though I'm using same code as model TEST1)

```
{%- set datasource = 'facebook' -%}

{%- set metric_dict = get_scoring_metrics(datasource) -%}

{{
    scoring(
      datasource = datasource,
      metric_dict = metric_dict
    )
}}
```

---

### macro scoring

```
{% macro scoring(datasource, metric_dict={} ) %}
--the query below means nothing. It's just an example to show that when this macro is called from test2.sql model, the metric_dict does not
--work as a dictionary but this macro receives metric_dict as a string (error- str objet has no attribute items).
--But when it's called from test1.sql model it receives metric_dict as a python dictionary.

  {% for i , j in  metric_dict.items() %}
        select {{ i }} , {{ j }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

---

### macro get_scoring_metrics

```
{% macro get_scoring_metrics(datasource) %}

    -- DICTIONARY THAT MAPS METRICS TO THEIR SUB-DIMENSIONS

{%- call statement('scoring_metric_query', fetch_result=True) -%}

    SELECT TO_JSON(PARSE_JSON('{'||LISTAGG(diq_subdim,',')||'}')) AS diq_metric
    FROM
        (
            SELECT subdim_name||':'||'['||scoring_metric||']' AS diq_subdim
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT '"'||subdimension ||'"' AS subdim_name,
                    LISTAGG(''''||scoring_metric ||'''' , ',') AS scoring_metric
                    FROM {{ ref('sample_data') }}
                    WHERE lower(datasource) = lower('{{ datasource }}')
                    GROUP BY subdimension
                ) T1
        ) T2

{%- endcall -%}

{% if execute %}

  {%- set query_result = load_result('scoring_metric_query')['data'][0][0] -%}
  {% set metric_dict = fromjson(query_result) %}

  {{ return(metric_dict) }}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}


-----------------------------------------------------------------
```